# How to refresh user control grid by using another user control event

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am developing windows application using C#. Need solution for below mentioned scenario. I have windows form containing two user control. First user control contains grid and when user click on any row of grid another user control display  details of selected cell. when I modify any data from details control I need to refresh data grid in parent control.

I am using below code to load child control.

```
private void GridInquiry_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    PanelParentControl.Controls.Clear();
    InquiryDetailsCls.InquiryID =  Convert.ToInt32(GridInquiry.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    CtrlInqDetails inqDetails = new CtrlInqDetails(InquiryDetailsCls.InquiryID, 1);
    inqDetails.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    PanelParentControl.Controls.Add(inqDetails);
}
```

Comment: try calling update method on the grid..or rebind the grid with the datasource after you add the new object. That should load it..

Comment: Hi Sumit, thanks for reply but I need any event to be executed on my parent form to identify when to rebind grid. as both user controls are different and I want to refresh parent grid from child control event.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to you to use the [Notification Center for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/438582/Csharp-NotificationCenter,),With this you can make a global event, register for this event anywhere in you code and to fire this event from anywhere in your code.

Comment: Hi, will you please share any example to implement this in user control.

Comment: In the link you have example(Demo) that using this mechanize and using winform.

Comment: Yes I downloaded demo and checking for how this fit in my requirement.